# Importing Data with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have flyway and spring-boot working correctly, but I can't seem to wire up my `spring.datasource.data` correctly.

If I have a file `src/main/resources/db/seeds/one_project.sql`.  I have tried the following inside my `application.properties` file.

```
# fully qualified path
spring.datasource.data=file:///fully/qualified/path/db/seeds/one_project.sql

# classpath specific
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/db/seeds/one_project.sql

# relative path
spring.datasource.data=/db/seeds/one_project.sql
```

The only thing I can actually get to work is to copy `one_project.sql` to `src/main/resources/schema.sql` ( even copying it to `src/main/resources/data.sql` does not work.

Is there something I am completely missing from the documentation?

I have been following along the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-database-initialization).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Default place for migration scripts is 'src/resources/db/migration' directory. From FlywayProperties class.   `/**
  * Locations of migrations scripts.
  */
 private List<String> locations = Arrays.asList("db/migration");`

Comment: Actually Flyway is the wrong tag here, since you don't use any Flyway functionality, if you want to import the data the way you described. This is plain Spring JDBC database initialization.

Comment: I removed the Flyway tag.

@AntonNovopashin I have migrations working correctly, this is about seeding data, not migrating the schema.  I want to give it some initial data

Comment: @Alex You can load your initial data with Flyway/Liquibase.

Comment: @AntonNovopashin I want flyway to manage my migrations so that when I deploy to prod it migrates the schema, but I don't want to put fake data when I deploy.  I would like to have a separate SQL script that can be used in development environments, but not in production

Comment: @Alex I do know liqubase supports profiles and you can easy solve your task but I don't how exactly to do the same with Flyway.

Comment: Do you have a message in the logs that says - "Could not send event to complete DataSource initialization" ? And did you try just data.sql and making sure that you remove the spring.datasource.data property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR

```
Create a blank schema.sql if you want your data.sql to run.
Also as stated in a comment it must execute one line such as `select 1` or `select 1 from dual`
```

You said

> The only thing I can actually get to work is to copy one_project.sql to src/main/resources/schema.sql

Which makes me think it's evident you don't have a schema.sql

So just create a blank schema.sql and then it will run one_project.sql

> Source Code -https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceInitializer.java

As you can see it gathers the schema locations and if schema resources are empty then it doesn't continue to run the data.sql (this is at the top of the runSchemaScripts() method)

Comment: This no longer works, as Spring is throwing an exception that the schema.sql cannot be blank

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski  true. A comment is not sufficient. workaround is something like "SELECT 1 from dual;" in `schema.sql`

Answer (score 6):

Stuck at that quite long.
My context: Spring Boot 2.2.6 + Hibernate 5.4 + script.sql in classpath(src/main/resources).
To make script executed at application start I was need to add in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.data=classpath:script.sql
```

And remove all comments BEFORE the actual code and BETWEEN code in script.sql.
Or if you need comments, add `SELECT 1;` on the next line after the line with comment. Because the next line after commented one seems to be ignored. No matter how many line breaks after line with comment you paste.

Comment: I figured out that comments problem appears only with `#` comments. With `--` or `/* */` comments there are no problems.

Answer (score 5):

As i can see it, Spring Boot executes the data scripts if one of the following conditions is true:

- The schema.sql script is present and the initialization is enabled (spring.datasource.initialize=true)
- If JPA and Hibernate is used and autoconfigured with Spring Boot: The property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is present (the value doesn't matter, you can give it an empty string or just "validate") and the initialization is enabled (spring.datasource.initialize=true).

Comment: I added `spring.datasource.initialize=true` and it had no effect.

Comment: Well, read my answer carefully, that is only one part, that you need. Do you use Hibernate with JPA?

Comment: I already have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property defined, so the only one missing was `spring.datasource.initialize=true` .  Still no change

Comment: @Alex Perhaps a silly question, but do you have Hibernate on the classpath?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson yes, reading and writing data to the database with hibernate works

Comment: `spring.datasource.initialize` was deprecated, use `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The way I got it working was by using the following properties

```
 spring.datasource.data=classpath:prod.sql
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASENAME?useSSL=false
 spring.datasource.username=USERNAME
 spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
 spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

`spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always` seems to do the trick

Comment: if you are using a socket  ?  like :          url: jdbc:mysql://google/${CLOUD_SQL_DATABASE_NAME:marketplace}?cloudSqlInstance=${DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID:qwiklabs-gcp-03-c2ba3b787460}:us-central1:mysql-db-container&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory

Comment: Thanks, it works. If you use maven sometimes project needs to be reimported to kinda update classpath.

Answer (score 3):

Try using classpath*, like the following:

```
spring.datasource.schema=classpath*:db/seeds/your_schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath*:db/seeds/one_project.sql
```

Comment: or if structure resources/sql/file1.sql and file2.sql is present, then use: spring.datasource.data=classpath:sql/file1.sql, classpath:sql/file2.sql

Answer (score 2):

As of Spring Boot **version 2.7** and onwards the provided here solution of

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.data=classpath:script.sql
```

will stop working since the properties `spring.datasource.data` and `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` have been removed from spring boot. The replacements `spring.sql.init.data-locations` and `spring.sql.init.mode` should be used instead.

So the solution would be

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:script.sql
```

See relevant [Spring Boot 2.7 changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7.0-Configuration-Changelog)