# import initial data into spring boot app

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-boot, import, spring-data-jpa

According to the documentation 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html to import data on startup you can define these 2 properties inside application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.data=data.sql
spring.datasource.schema=schema.sql
```

This works when you have both of these files, but i don't have schema. I am generating db schema using hibernate

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Previous workaround [Importing Data with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307051/importing-data-with-spring-boot) was to define file for schema.sql blank, but it doesn't work anymore. I will get exception that file can't be `blank or null`.

In spring application i simply defined

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="simpleDataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:dbscripts/data.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

and it worked.

Is there a way to have same behaviour also in springBoot?

Comment: Hi Any Luck with this issue ? Have you solved it ?

Comment: @pmanolov yeah, just remove properties in `application.properties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete `schema.sql` + config options and Spring Boot should automatically pick up only `sata.sql`.

Answer (score 2):

According to spring source code - `data.sql` will be invoked only if `schema.sql` file exist and it is not empty. So if you only need scripts from `data.sql` add some simple query to `schema.sql` like

```
SELECT 1;
```

Also in `application.properties` add

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

because default value is used only for embedded data sources.