# spring.datasource.data picked up, but script never executed

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, h2

I am trying to set up in-memory H2 tables for a test class in my Spring boot application.

My config looks something like:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: create-drop
  datasource:

    # not sure which one to use so added both just in case
    initialization-mode: always
    initialize: true

    platform: h2

    # casting a wide net here, but no cookie - completely ignored
    data: data-h2.sql,classpath*:data-h2.sql, classpath:data-h2.sql

    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
```

As you can see, I'm trying to load a `data-h2.sql` script upon db initialization.

Unfortunately, the property is ignored no matter the value.

I am certain the configuration file is being picked up properly (e.g. among others, I desperately added a `@Value("${spring.datasource.data}"` -annotated property in my test class and the value was indeed populated correctly).

As an alternative, I could annotate the test class with `@Sql("classpath:data-h2.sql")` which did run the script - however it did so for every test, while I wanted the script to be run once before any test execution.

I also tried removing that and using a blank `schema.sql` and moving the population to `data.sql` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307051/importing-data-with-spring-boot)), but Spring would complain about the empty schema file - which is useless to me, because my schema is auto-generated and I certainly don't want to re-create it (NB: probably a conflict with a hibernate property if memory serves).

I've browsed some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505952/how-to-populate-database-only-once-before-test-methods-in-spring-test), but the only [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488282/2353911) I could use, is not working.

The only solution I can see is to keep the `@Sql` annotation, but try and clear the tables after every test with another `@Sql` annotation launching another script on `@After`.

This seems insane to me - there *must* be a better solution.

Am I missing something more esoteric than it already is in my configuration?

Comment: side note: Shouldn't the `ddl-auto` property be configured under `spring.jpa.hibernate` instead of `spring.hibernate`?

Comment: @michalk looks like you're right - thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your file in the /main/resources directory (what you already did)

**Spring Boot 2:**

The correct property is:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Read more about this topic in the Spring Boot Documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc

**Spring Boot 1**

You only have to place data-h2.sql in the classpath

Read more about this topic in the Spring Boot Documentation: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc

Comment: Unfortunately the file *is* there, and as you can see from my configuration, the property is there too! But nope.

Comment: Elaborating on my comment above: "nope" means no script is executed with both file in place and property set in configuration. My version of spring boot is `1.5.8.RELEASE` is that's any relevant...

Comment: Yes this has changed from 1 to 2. I've added Spring Boot 1 to my answer

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. 1) seems so (no logs, properties are populated) 2) thanks for that - but it obviously still doesn't work for me no matter where the file is ...

Comment: Maybe you should try to create a minimal example. And if this works compare with your project

Comment: Sigh. You're probably right. Thought I might just have missed something obvious out there, but it's likely more relevant to something in the project itself. Will follow up when I have a chance. Thanks in the meantime.